# How to fix - Failed to fetch

Tags: raspberry-pi, repository, aptitude

Trying to install vim-gnome in Raspberry Pi3. Finally got error:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/p/perl/libperl5.20_5.20.2-3+deb8u8_armhf.deb: 404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
```

How to fix that?

Whole log:

```
sudo aptitude install vim-gnome
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gnome-mime-data libart-2.0-2 libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common{a} libbonoboui2-0{a} libbonoboui2-common libgail18 libglade2-0 libgnome-2-0 libgnome2-common libgnomecanvas2-0 
  libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0{a} libgnomeui-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgnomevfs2-extra liblua5.2-0{a} liborbit-2-0{a} libperl5.20{a} vim-gnome vim-gui-common{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 22 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 7,645 kB of archives. After unpacking 32.7 MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
Get: 1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libart-2.0-2 armhf 2.3.21-2 [63.8 kB]
Get: 2 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libbonobo2-common all 2.32.1-3 [243 kB]
Get: 3 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main liborbit-2-0 armhf 1:2.14.19-0.3 [196 kB]                                                                                             
Get: 4 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libbonobo2-0 armhf 2.32.1-3 [236 kB]                                                                                                  
Get: 5 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libglade2-0 armhf 1:2.6.4-2 [76.2 kB]                                                                                                 
Get: 6 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main gnome-mime-data all 2.18.0-1 [725 kB]                                                                                                 
Get: 7 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libgnomevfs2-common all 1:2.24.4-6 [763 kB]                                                                                           
Get: 8 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libgnomevfs2-0 armhf 1:2.24.4-6 [450 kB]                                                                                              
Get: 9 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libgnome2-common all 2.32.1-5 [936 kB]                                                                                                
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libperl5.20 armhf 5.20.2-3+deb8u8                                                                                                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Get: 10 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libgnome-2-0 armhf 2.32.1-5 [463 kB]                                                                                                 
Get: 11 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libgail18 armhf 2.24.25-3+deb8u2 [537 kB]                                                                                            
Get: 12 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libgnomecanvas2-common all 2.30.3-2 [132 kB]                                                                                         
Get: 13 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libgnomecanvas2-0 armhf 2.30.3-2 [94.7 kB]                                                                                           
Get: 14 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libbonoboui2-common all 2.24.5-2 [192 kB]                                                                                            
Get: 15 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libbonoboui2-0 armhf 2.24.5-2 [177 kB]                                                                                               
Get: 16 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libgnomeui-common all 2.24.5-3 [514 kB]                                                                                              
Get: 17 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libgnomeui-0 armhf 2.24.5-3 [285 kB]                                                                                                 
Get: 18 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main liblua5.2-0 armhf 5.2.3-1.1 [64.8 kB]                                                                                                
Get: 19 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main libgnomevfs2-extra armhf 1:2.24.4-6 [351 kB]                                                                                         
Get: 20 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main vim-gui-common all 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u3 [150 kB]                                                                                       
Get: 21 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main vim-gnome armhf 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u3 [993 kB]                                                                                          
Fetched 7,643 kB in 13s (566 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                    
Selecting previously unselected package libart-2.0-2:armhf.
(Reading database ... 124424 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libart-2.0-2_2.3.21-2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libart-2.0-2:armhf (2.3.21-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libbonobo2-common.
Preparing to unpack .../libbonobo2-common_2.32.1-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking libbonobo2-common (2.32.1-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liborbit-2-0:armhf.
Preparing to unpack .../liborbit-2-0_1%3a2.14.19-0.3_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking liborbit-2-0:armhf (1:2.14.19-0.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libbonobo2-0:armhf.
Preparing to unpack .../libbonobo2-0_2.32.1-3_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libbonobo2-0:armhf (2.32.1-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libglade2-0:armhf.
Preparing to unpack .../libglade2-0_1%3a2.6.4-2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libglade2-0:armhf (1:2.6.4-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gnome-mime-data.
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-mime-data_2.18.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-mime-data (2.18.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgnomevfs2-common.
Preparing to unpack .../libgnomevfs2-common_1%3a2.24.4-6_all.deb ...
Unpacking libgnomevfs2-common (1:2.24.4-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgnomevfs2-0:armhf.
Preparing to unpack .../libgnomevfs2-0_1%3a2.24.4-6_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libgnomevfs2-0:armhf (1:2.24.4-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgnome2-common.
Preparing to unpack .../libgnome2-common_2.32.1-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking libgnome2-common (2.32.1-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgnome-2-0:armhf.
Preparing to unpack .../libgnome-2-0_2.32.1-5_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libgnome-2-0:armhf (2.32.1-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgail18:armhf.
Preparing to unpack .../libgail18_2.24.25-3+deb8u2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libgail18:armhf (2.24.25-3+deb8u2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgnomecanvas2-common.
Preparing to unpack .../libgnomecanvas2-common_2.30.3-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libgnomecanvas2-common (2.30.3-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgnomecanvas2-0:armhf.
Preparing to unpack .../libgnomecanvas2-0_2.30.3-2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libgnomecanvas2-0:armhf (2.30.3-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libbonoboui2-common.
Preparing to unpack .../libbonoboui2-common_2.24.5-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libbonoboui2-common (2.24.5-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libbonoboui2-0:armhf.
Preparing to unpack .../libbonoboui2-0_2.24.5-2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libbonoboui2-0:armhf (2.24.5-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgnomeui-common.
Preparing to unpack .../libgnomeui-common_2.24.5-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking libgnomeui-common (2.24.5-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgnomeui-0:armhf.
Preparing to unpack .../libgnomeui-0_2.24.5-3_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libgnomeui-0:armhf (2.24.5-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblua5.2-0:armhf.
Preparing to unpack .../liblua5.2-0_5.2.3-1.1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking liblua5.2-0:armhf (5.2.3-1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgnomevfs2-extra:armhf.
Preparing to unpack .../libgnomevfs2-extra_1%3a2.24.4-6_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libgnomevfs2-extra:armhf (1:2.24.4-6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1~bpo8+1) ...
Processing triggers for gconf2 (3.2.6-3) ...
Setting up libart-2.0-2:armhf (2.3.21-2) ...
Setting up libbonobo2-common (2.32.1-3) ...
Setting up liborbit-2-0:armhf (1:2.14.19-0.3) ...
Setting up libbonobo2-0:armhf (2.32.1-3) ...
Setting up libglade2-0:armhf (1:2.6.4-2) ...
Setting up gnome-mime-data (2.18.0-1) ...
Setting up libgnomevfs2-common (1:2.24.4-6) ...
Setting up libgnomevfs2-0:armhf (1:2.24.4-6) ...
Setting up libgnome2-common (2.32.1-5) ...
Setting up libgnome-2-0:armhf (2.32.1-5) ...
Setting up libgail18:armhf (2.24.25-3+deb8u2) ...
Setting up libgnomecanvas2-common (2.30.3-2) ...
Setting up libgnomecanvas2-0:armhf (2.30.3-2) ...
Setting up libbonoboui2-common (2.24.5-2) ...
Setting up libbonoboui2-0:armhf (2.24.5-2) ...
Setting up libgnomeui-common (2.24.5-3) ...
Setting up libgnomeui-0:armhf (2.24.5-3) ...
Setting up liblua5.2-0:armhf (5.2.3-1.1) ...
Setting up libgnomevfs2-extra:armhf (1:2.24.4-6) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u10) ...
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/p/perl/libperl5.20_5.20.2-3+deb8u8_armhf.deb: 404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193
```

Comment: Stale sources - do an `apt-get update`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your local package indexes are outdated, you need to update them:

```
sudo aptitude update
```